Find all of the $\mathbb{Z}$ homomorphisms in $\hom _{\mathbb{Z}}\left ( \mathbb{Z}_{60},\mathbb{Z}^{60} \right )$
My problem is: Find all of $\mathbb{Z}$-module homomorphisms in $\hom _{\mathbb{Z}}\left ( \mathbb{Z}_{60},\mathbb{Z}^{60} \right )$, where $\mathbb{Z}^{60}$ is denoted for the direct sum of $60$ copies of $\mathbb{Z}$.
Let $\varphi : \mathbb{Z}_{60}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^{60}$, I think I should find the image of $\bar{1}$ first,$\varphi(\bar{1})$, but I get stuck on figuring out what $\varphi(\bar{1})$ should be?, I guess it should be in the  form $\left ( a_{i} \right )_{i\in I}, a_{i}\in\mathbb{Z},\forall i\in I=\left \{ 1,2,\cdots ,60 \right \}$, and then  what should I do to make $\varphi$ become $\mathbb{Z}$-module homomorphism? Can you please give me some hints? Thanks,

Hint:  $\mathbb Z/60\mathbb Z$ is cyclic, $1$ has order $60$.  How many elements in $\mathbb Z^{60}$ have order dividing $60$?

For any two positive integers $n$ and $m$, the only group homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ to $\mathbb{Z}^{m}$ is the trivial one.

Does this answer your question? Show that $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb Z_n, \mathbb Z) = 0$, for any $n \ge 2$. It shows that the 60 components $\Bbb Z_{60}\to\Bbb Z$ of any morphism $\Bbb Z_{60}\to\Bbb Z^{60}$ are all $0$.
